# Which is right in this content: hear or hearing?

Tags: grammar

> Friend: what's up?
>   Me: Hearing my friends screaming over a pillow.

Should *hear* be used instead of *hearing*?
If not, why then?

Comment: 'listening to my friends scream'

Comment: why not screaming? like I saw my friend crying?

Comment: nothing wrong with it, just sounds better to me. Something about two -ings in the same sentence sounds awkward.

Comment: Also use of ***over*** is unclear.  What is meant by this?  Are they arguing over a pillow?  (Arguing about ownership) are they yelling at each other with a pillow between them at chest height or below?  Do you mean through a pillow (the pillow is being held against their mouth)???  Something else?

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on context: if you are trying to say "I am listening to my friend, who is screaming over a pillow", then it's "hearing". If you are trying to command your friend to listen to your friends screaming over a pillow, then "hear" is appropriate.

The statement is also a little odd: as it stands, the sentence you put up indicates that you are listening to multiple people scream either about (implying *at* each other as well), or over the top of, a pillow.

"Hearing my friends *(possessive plural)* screaming *(plural)* over *(above, or possibly about?)* a pillow".

I kind of hope they aren't fighting about a pillow...

Comment: Not possessive plural, just plural. The statement is also odd because however exactly the friends are screaming over the poor pillow, hearing them do so is an odd thing to reply to a “what's up?”.